# Get connection to DataTable object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I have C# application that fills a GridView with data from a DataTable object, which is filled from parsing a text file. Now i want to do a master-detail scheme, where the master GridView shows an identifying column from the DataTable for all rows, and the detail GridView shows all the columns for that row.

All the examples I'm finding seem to require a SqlDataSource control (to provide the filtering mechanism), which then requires a connection to a database. I can't find how to provide this information when using only a DataTable data source. What provider would I use, and what would the connection string look like?

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have your `DataSource` (unless the data will change when you click a `GridViewRow`), so all you need is to get something like a Key from your current `GridView`, create a new `DataSource` by loading data from your `DataTable` with the selected key in your `GridView` and bind it to your new `GridView`. I could also suggest that you take a look to the `DetailsView`  control which is designed to do in fact what you are trying to accomplish here (master-details scheme).

Good luck my friend.

Comment: I certainly learned a couple things from this. One, I knew nothing about DetailsView, but I don't think I can use it (for the same reasons I'm asking this question: seems to require a db connection). Two, I'm having to put some code in the HeaderContent section of the ASP page (just like javascript!). Three, one can change the protection level of global variables. I hadn't known it was even an option.

Answer (score 0):

No connection string needed.  You already have the data in a DataTable, so you should be able to do something along the lines of:

```
myGridView.DataSource = myDataTable;
myGridView.Databind();
```

Comment: This is what I was doing until I decided to do a master GridView and then another GridView (for editing the whole row) for the detail (key to be passed from master to detail).